# Getting a list of MSSQL databases where a specific DB user does not have the required roles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I simply cannot solve a problem through which I think should be easy.

Have a view structured like this:

| Server name | Instance name | DB Name | DB User Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SERVER01 | INSTANCE01 | TESTDB | db_datareader |

This view is giving back a list of databases where a specific user, let's call it Backup01,  is present.

I need to write a query which validates that on each DB this Backup01 user has the required roles for it to work. This query I guess should give back a list of DBs where the user is present but without 1 or more required roles (maybe with the servername, instancename, dbname and the missing db role?).

How should I go through this list of databases with this validation?

Comment: Are your database names known in advance? Otherwise you need dynamic SQL

Comment: To validate "known" this doesn't mean "The list is in a table", but more, that they are a very specific known list. For example, the system databases in an instance are known: `master`, `msdb`, `tempdb`, and `model`.

Comment: Yes, the database names are known and collected via a collection job.

Comment: I mean known as in "you know them already when you write the query". Sounds like not?

Comment: yes, I know them already, they are stored in a separate table.